# Can't access dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

Can't acces dynamically generated element:
This is my function for json request:

```
$.getJSON('/getJSON.php?selectorcat='+var1, function(jsonData){

var LI_list_html = '';
var sum = 0;

if(jsonData[0])
    {
        $.each(jsonData, function(i,value)
        {
        var catname = jsonData[i].name;
        var id = jsonData[i].id;
        var DIV_html = catname;

        LI_list_html = LI_list_html+'<li class="selectorsub" data-catselectsub="'+id+'" id="SelectorSubcat_'+id+'">'+DIV_html+'</li>';
        });
        }
        else
        {
            LI_list_html = 'No subcats there..';
        }
```

So when i get the generated html like this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="selectorsub" data-catselectsub="169" id="SelectorSubcat_169">CAT1</li>
   <li class="selectorsub" data-catselectsub="170" id="SelectorSubcat_170">CAT2</li>
   <li class="selectorsub" data-catselectsub="171" id="SelectorSubcat_171">CAT3</li>
   <li class="selectorsub" data-catselectsub="172" id="SelectorSubcat_172">CAT4</li>
</ul>
```

I can't acces the li-element trought this:

```
$("[id^=SelectorSubcat_]").click(function() {
   alert($(this).data('catselectsub'));
});
```

I think the elemen that is generated isn't ready DOM that's why can't acces them.

Comment: You are 100% true on the reason why, and this is why we have [delegated events](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). By the way your jquery selector is very complicated, in this case you better use the class from where I see it.

Comment: Why not rely on the `.selectorsub` class instead of `[id^=]`? Not only it's more concise it will perform better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are creating elements dynamically, You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', "[id^=SelectorSubcat_]", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container For better performance.

Comment: This is a bad practice to delegate such events to the document. Events should be delegated to the closest static parent for performance reasons. Seeing your reputation you probably know that but I think it should be part of your answer.