# How to check a document.click inside a dropdown with elements dinamically created?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm using the code below on my content_script to get mouse target, however, it doesn't get the 'click' trigger on a dropdown with elements created at runtime.
By that I mean, I can see the target of everything, even the dropdown itself, just the elements created are not triggering the function.

```
$(window).on('click', function(event){
{
console.log(event.target);
}
```

good to mention mousemove works fine

```
document.onmousemove = function(e)
{
console.log(e.target);
}
```

my dropdown is basically a bunch of 'li' inside a 'ul' element, created from another js, displayed as a dropdown, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The event binding code must be executed when the element it binds to is already there. You need to use `Event Delegation` with.`on()` Same question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945713/3116042)
example:

```
$(document).on('.select2-results__options .select2-results__option','selector', function(event){
  console.log(event.target);
});
```

Comment: I am already using .on() and the selector haven't made any change, I can indeed click on the search bar created dynamically on the top of my dropdown, however, the li elements does not seem to trigger the click function

Comment: @FelipeAmorim Can you share your code in a pen so we get a better look at it?

Comment: As the source code and the source code compiled with the js are different, follows on the image link, the source code compiled  http://prntscr.com/lbsy5o

Comment: "*The event binding code must be executed when the element it binds to is already there*" - OP is using `$(window)` - it's likely that already exists.   OP - change to the more common `$(document).on` (in the first instance, not the final/ideal solution) to be sure.